# Using AWS RDS Postgres: Create a superuser with access to all tables (also future created ones)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

In AWS RDS (A managed Database service), we cannot create real superusers. There is a user RDS calls Master User, which can create new users, databases, tables, etc.

However, when another user has created a table inside of a database, the master user cannot access it.

I want to setup the master user that is has access to all tables in all databases (also for future created ones) as well as one user that will have read-only-access to all tables in a specific database (also future created ones).